Rotating file handler rolls over incorrectly, overwrites backups
I have a flask application functioning as an API. It's deployed on an NGINX server to 6 different ports. I have a remote log set up to a single location on a different server. It's using RotatingFileHandler with a threshold of ~5mb with 2 backups. I'll post the configuration below:
class OneLineExceptionFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def formatException(self, exc_info):
        """
        Format an exception so that it prints on a single line.
        """
        result = super(OneLineExceptionFormatter, self).formatException(exc_info)
        return repr(result)  # or format into one line however you want to

    def format(self, record):
        s = super(OneLineExceptionFormatter, self).format(record)
        if record.exc_text:
            s = s.replace('\n', '') + '|'
        return s

logger = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
my_handler = RotatingFileHandler(path_to_log, mode='a', maxBytes = 5 * 1024 * 1024, backupCount=2, encoding=None, delay=False)
f = OneLineExceptionFormatter('%(asctime)s|%(levelname)s|%(message)s|','%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
my_handler.setFormatter(f)
logger.addHandler(my_handler)

Sometimes, it will roll over correctly, but other times the backups will have 11 to 15kb and have activity from the same time but on different ports. Furthermore, sometimes a hidden file will appear (ex. filename .nfs00000000000814940000000a) that will also have some activity, but will disappear after a day or so.
I have read that Python loggers don't work with multiple processes writing to the same log. The solution in that case seems to be setting up a separate process with a socket that can queue the activity before writing it to the log. This isn't really that situation, but I imagine it's closer to that then multithreading. I can't seem to replicate this and the behavior seems to be erratic. Hoping someone has some idea of how to handle this because it's a total mystery to me.
